# Missing attendees/contacts from Outlook calendar and mail (Office 2013)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, lync-2013

At some point, the attendees/contacts section of my outlook 2013 are no longer present.

As far as I know, I have not changed the view (this issue is present in both the meeting dialogue and the email dialogue), and I can't seem to find where to alter the view.

**Before** (bottom right of the dialogue)

[image]

**Now**

[image]

I am suspecting that this has something to do with the Lync 2013 plug-in.
Hence the 'status' column to the left of the contact section.

Any help with getting it back again, is much appreciated!

Comment: View Ribbon, People Pane. See if it is turned off. You want either Normal or Minimal. I had to disable Lync add-on to confirm the setting, but People Pane seems to be a standard Outlook 2013 feature.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by Outlook, as the social connector plugin was disabled due to causing Outlook start slowly.

Enabling the add-in made it all work again :)

File -> Info -> Slow and Disabled Add-ins -> Manage Add-ins